# Aplicación web no reconoce .dll que contiene clases que contienen la letra "ñ" en el nombre

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb

Estoy trabajando en el desarrollo de una aplicación web en asp.net en la que tengo que utilizar unas dlls que me proporcionan. Estas dlls contienen las clases, y los controladores que tengo que utilizar. Por ejemplo el que me da problemas es `CompañiaInfo` y `CompañíaController`.

Lo que ocurre es que el desarrollo, mientras voy probando la app a través de visual studio e issexpress no me da el fallo, pero al desplegar la aplicación en el servidor, todos los objetos de las clases anteriores se quedan a null.

He configurado el `web.config` con la region en español y el concodig en `UTF-8` pero sigue igual el error.

No consigo solucionarlo y pienso que es por la `ñ` de las clases que me proporcionan.
Si alguien sabe comp solucionarlo estaría muy agradecido. Gracias, un saludo.

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, te sugerimos revisar [ask]. saludos.